# What is the Zhu algebra of a lattice vertex algebra?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, vertex-algebras

Associated to a vertex algebra $V$ is an associative algebra $A(V)$, the *Zhu algebra*. Its defining property is approximately that the representations of $V$ and of $A(V)$ are the same.

In [vertex operator algebras associated to affine and Virasoro algebras](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077294666), Frenkel and Zhu prove for instance that the Zhu algebra of the affine vertex algebra $V_k(\mathfrak{g})$ is $U(\mathfrak{g})$.

**Question:** Is the Zhu algebra of the vertex algbera $V_k(L)$ associated to lattice $L$ known?

Writing $\mathfrak{h}=L\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}}\mathbf{C}$, there is a map $V_k(\mathfrak{h})\hookrightarrow V_k(L)$, which gives a map $U(\mathfrak{h})\to A(V_k(L))$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the group algebra of $L^*/L$?

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd I have no idea. If you find a reference, I'd be happy to accept that as an answer.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9605032

Comment: I don't know a reference. I just (perhaps mistakenly) had assumed it. I will have to read the link Reimundo posted. @ReimundoHeluani I suggest you repost that link (perhaps with one-sentence summary) as an answer?

Comment: The truth of the matter is: I never think about, nor use, Zhu's algebra. I recognize that it is really important. But in RCFT, what you care about is the category Rep(V) of representations for V, not some particular algebra A whose module theory approximates Rep(V). I mean, we don't even have, in general, an equivalence Mod(A(V)) = Rep(V)!

Comment: Lattice VOAs were, afaik, one of the very first classes of VOAs whose representations were completely understood. In the positive definite case, L*/L is well-known to parameterize the irreps of V_L, and also of the group algebra of L*/L. Hence my (wrong) assumption.

Comment: sorry @TheoJohnson-Freyd for not being verbose, still at the clinic for the birth of my second baby. That paper computes the Zhu algebra in the even lattice case, it starts with an example in rank one to show it's not something trivial. There are newer results in the odd case that escape my memory, but a quick search through the papers referencing this one should find them.

Comment: @ReimundoHeluani Congratulations!

Comment: In RCFT, there is a 1-1 correspondence between Irr(V) <---> Irr(A(V)),  W<---> lowest weight subspace of W (let us call it W_0). Then A(V) is equivalent to \bigoplus End(W_0), where the direct sum is over all (equivalence classes of) irreducibles of V.

Answer (score 5):

I'm expanding Reimundo Heluani's [link](https://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9605032), which gives the answer when $L$ is an even positive definite lattice. Write $\mathfrak{h}=L\otimes_{\mathbf{Z}}\mathbf{C}$. Every $\alpha\in L$ gives two elements, $E_\alpha\in \mathbf{C}[L]$ and $\alpha\in\mathfrak{h}$.

The Zhu algebra is
$$A(V_L)\ =\ U(\mathfrak{h})\otimes\mathbf{C}[L]/\ (\alpha -(\alpha,\alpha)/2)E_\alpha.$$
The algebra structure on $ U(\mathfrak{h})$ is the usual one, the structure on $\mathbf{C}[L]$ is almost the usual one
$$E_\alpha\cdot E_\beta\ =\ \text{const.}\cdot E_{\alpha+\beta}$$
(for the constants see equations 2.9 and 2.10 of [arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9605032](http://arxiv.org/abs/q-alg/9605032)), which together with
$$[\alpha, E_\beta]\ =\ (\alpha,\beta) E_\beta$$
give the algebra structure on $U(\mathfrak{h})\otimes\mathbf{C}[L]$.

It is a finitely generated algebra, and contains a copy of $U(\mathfrak{h})$ within it.